# Phonegap jQuery ajax call fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cordova

I know there a lot of questions about this already but I have yet to find one which actually helps.

I'm using Phonegap to make an app which makes use of an in-house REST API for retrieving news items. I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 (and jQuery mobile 1.3.2 and mustache.js). Everything works fine when I test it on a local xampp server, it only stops working when compiled and deployed to a device.

Here is my current `$.ajax` call (invoked on `deviceReady`):

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

// Load news items.
$.mobile.loading("show");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "http://mynewsapi.com/items",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    timeout: 10000,  // 10 seconds
    error: function(xhr, status, exception){
        $("#msg").text("Error: "+status+" - "+exception);
        $.mobile.loading("hide");
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#msg").text("Got JSONP response");
        console.debug(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
            data.items[i].image = data.imageHost+data.items[i].image;
            html = Mustache.render('<li><a href="#article?id={{id}}" data-transition="slidefade"><img src="{{image}}" style="top:auto"><h2>{{title}}</h2></a></li>', data.items[i]);
            $("#newsList").append(html);
            $("#newsList").listview("refresh");
        };
        $.mobile.loading("hide");
    }
});
```

- I have tried with and without setting `$.support.cors` and `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages`
- In my config.xml I have `<access origin="*" />`
- I was originally using normal JSON but have more recently been trying JSONP to see if it would work any better (nope)
- The response from the server includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header
- Accessing the API URL in the device's browser works fine

When using JSONP I get the error `parsererror - Error: jQueryxxx_xxx was not called` and when using normal JSON I would get `error - Unknown`.

I have run out of things to try. Why isn't this working?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * will not work. By specification Origin: null (sent for file-URIs) is not accepted. But I don't think, that this is an issue here.

Comment: I was a last-ditch effort to try and get it working. I wasn't expecting it to have an effect but I thought it would be worth a try anyway

Comment: what kind of device ios? android bb10 or windows phone 8?

Comment: Testing on Windows Phone 7. A coworker has tested it on his iPhone and reports the same problem

Comment: There is a good remote-debugger for ios Maybe you can see some logs. debug.phonega.com may also be helpful.

Comment: @TomSavage Exactly i am having the same problem like you....

Comment: @TomSavage I'm having same problem, anyone got any solution? Working perfectly on local browser, fails when deploying into emulator.

Comment: @Any one with solution or links?